# How to use a CMD command in c++?

Tags: c++, cmd

I want to use this cmd command

```
ROBOCOPY D:\folder1 D:\folder2 /S /E
```

with conditions to copy the contents of folder1 to folder2

```
if(i == 1)
```

and,

```
if(i == 2)

ROBOCOPY D:\folder3 D:\folder4 /S /E
```

to copy the contents of folder3 to folder4

what should i do?

Comment: system("Yourcommand"), WinExec, or CreateProcess in order of simpler to better.

Comment: Why even use Robocopy? Why not copy the directories with C++?

Comment: Did you escape the `\\` if you hardcoded the path as a string literal?

Comment: @drescherjm Good spot! That's why I've been using `/` in my answer.

Comment: @Biffen Is there a simple/portable code to do so?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ None that I know of in the standard library. But then Robocopy isn't exactly standard library either.

Comment: @Biffen _"But then Robocopy isn't exactly standard library either."_ Should work well enough for the [tag:cmd] context.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was *literally* asking *why* one would use Robocopy; it seems a bit like an XY problem. But sure, it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"what should i do?"*

You simply do this (using the **[`std::system()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system)** function):

```
#include <cstdlib>

// ...

if(i == 1) {
    std::system("ROBOCOPY D:/folder1 D:/folder2 /S /E");
}
else if(i == 2) {
    std::system("ROBOCOPY D:/folder3 D:/folder4 /S /E");
}
```

---

Note that for string literals like `"D:\folder3"`, you'll need to escape `'\'` characters, with another `'\'`: `"D:\\folder3"`.
Or even two more, depending on the interpreting command shell (should work on windows [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) without doing so): `"D:\\\\folder3"`.
The easier way though, is to use the simpler to write `'/'` character, that's accepted for specifying windows pathes lately as well.

Comment: Thanks you, you answer helped me, but std::system("ROBOCOPY D:/folder1 D:/folder2 /S /E"); is not working for me instead but std::system("ROBOCOPY D:\\\\folder1 D:\\\\folder2 /S /E"); works. can you explain what is escape characters and why do we need to use them?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to call the standard library function `system`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

If you need more flexibility, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx `CreateProcess` is the thing to go for - the STARTUPINFO argument lets you do things like pass it custom input and capture its output too.

Comment: Show small inline samples please, instead of just providing the links. That would gloriously improve your answer.