# How to run an executable with spaces using std::system on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, path

How can an executable with spaces be run using std::system on Windows *without using C++11*?

I've tried the seemingly obvious placing quotes around the path with spaces, but in the console window that pops up running the command I get a message that indicates that the full executable path is being split on spaces.  For example, I've tried the following:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    int no_spaces_forward_rc = std::system("c:/IronPython2.7/ipy -c \"print 'no_spaces_forward'\"");
    // no_spaces_forward_rc is 0 and "no_spaces_forward" is written to console window

    int spaces_forward_rc    = std::system("\"c:/Program Files (x86)/IronPython 2.7/ipy\" -c \"print 'spaces_forward'\"");
    // spaces_forward_rc is 1, and "'c:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." is written to console window

    int no_spaces_backward_rc = std::system("c:\\IronPython2.7\\ipy -c \"print 'no_spaces_backward'\"");
    // no_spaces_backward_rc is 0 and "no_spaces_backward" is written to console window

    int spaces_backward_rc    = std::system("\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython 2.7\\ipy\" -c \"print 'spaces_backward'\"");
    // spaces_backward_rc is 1, and "'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." is written to console window

    int no_spaces_double_backward_rc = std::system("c:\\\\IronPython2.7\\\\ipy -c \"print 'no_spaces_double_backward'\"");
    // no_spaces_double_backward_rc is 0, and no_spaces_double_backward is written to console window

    int spaces_double_backward_rc    = std::system("\"c:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\IronPython 2.7\\\\ipy\" -c \"print 'spaces_double_backward'\"");
    // spaces_double_backward_rc is 1, and "'c:\\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." is written to console window

    int spaces_double_double_backward_rc    = std::system("\\\"c:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\IronPython 2.7\\\\ipy\\\" -c \"print 'spaces_double_double_backward'\"");
    // spaces_dobule_double_backward_rc is 1, and "'\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython 2.7\\ipy\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." is written to console window

    return 0;
}
```

I've verified that running `"c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\ipy" -c "print 'spaces_backward'"` directly in a cmd prompt works, and I'm pretty sure I don't just have a typo.  This is driving me nuts -- any help would be greatly appreciated!

(I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and compiling with subsystem Console if that helps.)

Comment: Use doubled escaped `\\\\\` backslashes (see here also: [How to use a CMD command in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27881455/1413395) )

Comment: Thanks, but double escaped backslashes didn't work for me either.  I updated the question to include that code that failed me too.  Does double backslashes work for you?

Comment: You also may need to _double_ escape the quote `"` characters: `\\\"`. Ideally use a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) and escape anything as you would do feeding a CMD call.

Comment: Are you just messing with me, lol?  I'm trying all sorts of double escaping right now and can't get anything to work.  If you could post a working example, that would be really helpful.

Comment: What? I'm just trying to help. What's wrong? _"I'm trying all sorts of double escaping right now"_ That's why I mentioned the raw string literals from the documentation. I also remember having seen a _real dupe_ for your question, just don't have it at hand.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It seems like I'm getting closer.  Can you please see my updated question and see if I'm escaping the `"` correctly?

Comment: I don't think raw string literals are supported by Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Incidentally, if you run across this sort of thing again, the simplest troubleshooting approach is to run `cmd /c whatever` in the console (rather than just `whatever`) because that's what `system("whatever")` actually does. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for `cmd.exe` has a nasty twist.  From `cmd.exe /?`:

> ```
> 1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
>     on the command line are preserved:
>
>     - no /S switch
>     - exactly two quote characters
>     - no special characters between the two quote characters,
>       where special is one of: &<>()@^|
>     - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
>       two quote characters
>     - the string between the two quote characters is the name
>       of an executable file.
> ```

To make the behaviour consistent, the `std::system` call should use the `/S` switch, and embed the command in quote marks.  Sadly, it doesn't.  This means that this will work:

```
std::system("\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe\" h:\\documents\\documentation\\misc\\calendar 1999.pdf");
```

but this seemingly trivial variant won't:

```
std::system("\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe\" \"h:\\documents\\documentation\\misc\\calendar 1999.pdf\"");
```

To fix the problem, the *entire* command, *including* the quoted path to the executable, must be surrounded in quotes:

```
std::system("\"\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe\" \"h:\\documents\\documentation\\misc\\calendar 1999.pdf\"\"");
```

In your example, that would be

```
std::system("\"\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\IronPython 2.7\\ipy\" -c \"print 'spaces_backward'\"\"");
```

Comment: Curiously, it would seem that the open and close brackets do *not* count as special characters, despite what the help says.  If they did, my first example wouldn't have worked, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

OK this code using a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), actually works for me (VS2013 Express):

```
std::string cmd = R"cmd("C:\Program Files (x86)\doxygen\bin\doxygen.exe")cmd";
system(cmd.c_str());
```

For unsupported raw string literals, the traditionally escaped string literal should look as follows 1:

```
std::string cmd = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\doxygen\\bin\\doxygen.exe\"";
```

---

The reason for these *double escapings* is, that `system()` actually calls `cmd` which expects double quotes `"` enclosing the command line to execute.

---

<sub>1) As easy to see, this is error prone for missing a `\` somewhere.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I can't use this feature of C++11, because my compiler (VS2012) doesn't support it.

Comment: @JDiMatteo I've showed the traditional alternative as well.

Comment: `std::system("\"c:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\IronPython 2.7\\\\ipy\"")` works but `std::system("\"c:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\IronPython 2.7\\\\ipy\" -c \"print 1\"")` doesn't...

Comment: std::system("\"\"c:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\IronPython 2.7\\\\ipy\" -c \"print 1\"\"") worked -- any idea why?

Comment: @JDiMatteo Could it be that `ipy` also needs (even more) escaped characters using the `-c` option? That's a very specific problem it seems (may be you research on `ipy -c` documentation additionally). Also the first `\"` at `print`, actually closes the very opening `\"`.

Comment: I'm not accepting this answer because the double backslashes doesn't work unless I double quote, and if I double quote then I can just use forward slashes, so the double backslashes seems to just be a distraction.  This doesn't seem specific to ipy, e.g. see the double quoting at http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/1723/

Comment: @JDiMatteo _"This doesn't seem specific to ipy"_ No it isn't, see the updated part of my last comment.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me through all this!

Comment: @JDiMatteo De Nada! As mentioned in my footnote, it's error prone and easy to miss something.

Comment: The backslashes in the path shouldn't need to be doubled up like that.  The command processor doesn't do anything to backslashes, otherwise you'd need to double them up whenever you typed a command.

Comment: Your example works only because there are exactly two quote marks.  The OPs command has more than two, so you need an extra pair of quote marks as per my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, I wrote a little class `command` that encapsulates [Harry Johnston's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27976653/17751361) and makes using `system` for quoted paths spaces very easy.

Usage:

```
ifs::win::command c;
std::filesystem::path source = "c:\\my folder\\file.txt";
std::filesystem::path destination = "c:\\another folder\\another file.txt";
try {
    c << "copy " << source << " " << destination;
    c.run();
}
catch (ifs::win::cmd_error& e) {
    std::cout << "command: " << e.command() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "result: " << e.res() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "default error message: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Get `ifs_win.h/cpp` [from this repo](https://github.com/redocrepus/ifs).

(There is also `std::string runAndGetOutput();`)

Tested with c++17 on Win10 and Win11.