# xcopy command via C++ 'system' not working

Tags: c++, system, xcopy

I'm trying to copy files from one folder to another via xcopy in my C++ application.

The command outputs : "Invalid number of parameters"

here is the code:

```
system("xcopy H:\Temp\Configurations C:\temp\TSE /E");
```

If i try the same command directly in the command prompt, it works perfectly. It just does not work when i call it from my c++ code.

Comment: i have tried `system("xcopy H:\\Temp\\Configurations C:\\temp\\TSE /E");` still no luck

Comment: try `system("\"xcopy H:\\Temp\\Configurations C:\\temp\\TSE /E\"")`

Comment: @MartinBa It worked! Thank you! can you explain why i need 2 quotations?

Comment: This is [why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27976653/5583153)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
system("\"xcopy H:\\Temp\\Configurations C:\\temp\\TSE\"");
```

Thanks to @MartinBa

Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931134/return-value-of-system-function-call-in-c-used-to-run-a-python-program), Thank @Nacho for the link